# Pandoc: automatically convert URLs into hyperlinks

Tags: hyperlink, pandoc

Is there an option which automatically converts URLs into hyperlinks in Pandoc?

E.g.

```
http://www.test.com
```

should become

```
[http://www.test.com](http://www.test.com)
```

Or even cooler would be without the protocol:

```
[www.test.com](http://www.test.com)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just surround them in `<>` : `<http://www.test.com>`

```
echo "<http://example.com>" | pandoc
<p><a href="http://example.com" class="uri">http://example.com</a></p>
```

That will not work without the `http://` though. See the [documentation](http://pandoc.org/README.html#automatic-links).

Comment: This looks good, but in my case, the link is also surrounded by a `<code class="url">...</code>`. I'm not sure whether I like this. Is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 9):

Actually now you can use a command line option when you specify the input format

```
$ echo "http://example.com" | pandoc -f markdown+autolink_bare_uris
<p><a href="http://example.com" class="uri">http://example.com</a></p>
```

Note: I used pandoc version 2.11.4